# duplicates of documents getting created in jdbc river index (elastic search)

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm pulling data from my database whose table name is **Categories** which has columns **Cat_id** and **Cat_name**. I currently have 6 rows as my test data and started river instance with the following configuration with POSTMAN HTTP client -

```
     http://localhost:9200/_river/test/_meta 
       {
                "type" : "jdbc",
                "jdbc" : {
                        "url" : "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/elastic",
                        "user" : "root",
                        "password" : "password",
                        "sql" : "select Cat_id from Categories",
                        "index" : "sample",
                        "schedule" : "0/10 * * ? * *",
                        "autocommit" : true

                 }
}
```

The problem is, as I've scheduled for 10 seconds, query runs for every 10 seconds and duplicates of data is getting created in the index. That is, 
if my test data is -

```
       Cat_id      Cat_name
         1          Books
         2          Mobiles
         3          Laptops
```

My resulting index would get updated for every 10 seconds and same data gets added for every 10 seconds. That is, copies of data would be created.

I want only changes of data to be added to my index while no duplicates are created for my existing data ( Ex: Books,Mobiles,Laptops ).

Comment: Seem you did not specify the ID of documents. Try changing your SQL to : `select Cat_id as _id, * from Categories` and check

Comment: Thank you. It did solve my problem partially. When I add a new row in my database, changes are reflected in my index. That is, new data gets added to the index but when I delete the row in my database, the data that was deleted still remain in my index.Any suggestions on how to update the index  when indexed row of database is deleted?